# What Datawarehouse can process geospatial informations?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, database

I'm currently using a PostgreSQL database with the PostGIS extension. My querys are growing to big for my inhouse server, so I would like to port this into the cloud.

The querys mainly compute the distance between a table of geometrys and a table of points, returning all points within a certain distance to the geometry.

Does any cloud DWH (BigQuery, Redshift, ...) support processing geospatial information? If not, do you guys have an idea on how to go on with my problem?

edit: As requested by @JohnPowellakaBarça I'm posting the SQL query + explain that leads to my machine crashing.

```
explain
select t1.osm_id as building_osm_id, t2.osm_id as poi_osm_id, 
t1.centroid::geography <-> t2.geom::geography as distance
from germany_buildings_centroid t1, germany_poi_classes_transformed t2
where t1.st_x <= (t2.st_x+0.01) AND t1.st_x >= (t2.st_x-0.01) 
AND t1.st_y <= (t2.st_y+0.01) AND t1.st_y >= (t2.st_y-0.01)
AND ST_DWithin(t1.centroid::geography, t2.geom::geography,1000);


Gather  (cost=1000.00..48193265925353.62 rows=809798 width=24)
   Workers Planned: 2
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..48193265722916.41 rows=337416 width=24)
         Join Filter: ((t1.st_x <= (t2.st_x + '0.01'::double precision)) AND (t1.st_x >= (t2.st_x - '0.01'::double precision)) AND (t1.st_y <= (t2.st_y + '0.01'::double precision)) AND (t1.st_y >= (t2.st_y - '0.01'::double precision)) AND ((t1.centroid)::geography && _st_expand((t2.geom)::geography, '1000'::double precision)) AND ((t2.geom)::geography && _st_expand((t1.centroid)::geography, '1000'::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin((t1.centroid)::geography, (t2.geom)::geography, '1000'::double precision, true))
         ->  Parallel Seq Scan on germany_buildings_centroid t1  (cost=0.00..1304445.57 rows=11660458 width=56)
         ->  Seq Scan on germany_poi_classes_transformed t2  (cost=0.00..265650.37 rows=7031637 width=56)
```

Indexes on my tables:

```
           table_name            |               index_name               | column_name
---------------------------------+----------------------------------------+-------------
 germany_buildings_centroid      | idx_german_building_centroid_centroid | centroid
 germany_buildings_centroid      | idx_german_building_centroid_geom     | geom
 germany_poi_classes_transformed | idx_germany_poi_classes_transformed    | geom
```

After changing the query:

```
  select t1.osm_id as building_osm_id, t2.osm_id as poi_osm_id
from germany_buildings_centroid t1, germany_poi_classes_transformed t2
where ST_DWithin(t1.centroid::geography, t2.geom::geography,1000);
                                                                                                                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather  (cost=1000.00..46609808612882.03 rows=65674991 width=16)
   Workers Planned: 2
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..46609802044382.93 rows=27364580 width=16)
         Join Filter: (((t1.centroid)::geography && _st_expand((t2.geom)::geography, '1000'::double precision)) AND ((t2.geom)::geography && _st_expand((t1.centroid)::geography, '1000'::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin((t1.centroid)::geography, (t2.geom)::geography, '1000'::double precision, true))
         ->  Parallel Seq Scan on germany_buildings_centroid t1  (cost=0.00..1304522.12 rows=11668112 width=40)
         ->  Seq Scan on germany_poi_classes_transformed t2  (cost=0.00..265691.35 rows=7035735 width=40)
```

Comment: I think you will need to be a lot more specific about what kind of queries you are running before anyone can intelligently answer that.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry. I added this information to the post.

Comment: right now I run postgres with postgis on a windows go daddy server and there is wicked lack connecting to it and running queries

Comment: How big are your tables? You might be able to optimise what you have rather than going to the cloud. You can,of course, run Postgres in the cloud. There is also geomesa, which supports a lot of functionality and sits on top of BigTable, Cassandra, etc

Comment: My tables are roughly 28.1 Mio (geometry table) rows and 15.4 Mio rows (point table). Holding an osm_id, a geometry column and some additional information that are not necessary for the query. I'm running a Ubuntu machine with and intel i7-8700 and 64GB of RAM.

Comment: That doesn't seem so big. It may well be that you just need some optimizations. Could you post an example query and the Explain output. I'm not against the cloud, just trying to avoid unnecessary time and money

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça I added the query + explain to the main post. Thank you for your help and any insights are appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that you have two sequence scans and a nested loop and no index scans on the geometry columns. The reason for this are the two `WHERE t1.st_x <= (t2.st_x+0.01) AND t1.st_x >= (t2.st_x-0.01)`  clauses. Because you have an expression on ST_X and ST_Y, no index is being used. You would be better off first using ST_DWithin to reduce possible rows and then apply the other two where conditions. The other possibility would be to rewrite the ST_X/ST_Y parts so that they too can use within type logic or create a functional index if that is not possible.

Comment: I realize my error now. I wanted to use st_x and st_y to reduce the rows needed to compare. I don't think that putting them behind ST_DWithin has any additional value, correct? Using only ST_DWithin I still don't get any index scans. Am I doint something wrong?

Comment: Show the new query, and explain, please.

Comment: Attached in the main post.

Comment: Ok, I suspect the issue might be with the cast to geography and the SRID. What datatypes are centroid and geom and why are you casting to geography? I suspect this is why the index is being ignored.

Answer (score 2):

AWS Athena supports some GIS functionality: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-geospatial-data.html

BigQuery just announced Alpha of its GIS functionality at GCP Next '18.
The announcement and link to Alpha signup form is here:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/bridging-the-gap-between-data-and-insights
They also blogged about a task solved using similar ST_DWithin join:
https://towardsdatascience.com/using-bigquerys-new-geospatial-functions-to-interpolate-temperatures-d9363ff19446